# File tree on Linux via ifuse doesn't match ipad

Tags: ipad, unix, pdf

I have managed to get the linux tools idevicepair and ifuse working. I created a directory called ipad and I see Books, DCIM, Downloads iTunes_Control PhotoData Photos and Recordings. I can see them in both a terminal and Nautilis (dolphin).

All I want to do with this ipad is use it for reading pdfs. The problem is when I copy a file to the directory on the linux box (ipad then some subdirectory) they are not visible on the ipad itself. It is as if the ipad doesn't have the same directory tree. Yet I can click on the file in nautilus and it is quite obvious the file is on the ipad.

Do I have to root the ipad to see a real file tree structure?

Comment: With which iPad app do you want to open the PDF afterwards? Can you enable SMB sharing on your Linux machine and then use the Files app on the iPad to load PDFs into your iPad?

Comment: I loaded Foxit. I really have no preference to the pdf app.

Comment: Sorry if this is a duplicate answer. The stackexchange interface is confusing. I am using Foxit.  I have no preference for pdf app. I can't find my ipad via nmap so  I think samba is not a solution. My original question is what is up with the file tree on an ipad. What I see via ifuse is not what I see on the ipad itself.

Answer (score 2):

I installed the app shellfish. This let me ssh from the ipad into the linux box. I couldn't figure out the IP address of the network (via usb). I installed the app VLC and it identified the IP address of the ipad. From that point, I could nmap on the linux box to find the IP address of the linux box. I cannot ssh into the ipad. nmap verifies that the port is not open. But as I said the I can ssh in the direction from the ipad to the linux box. This did require setting up sshd on the linux box.I suppose now that I have addresses I could set up samba but ssh/sftp is fine. Probably more secure. I only allow the IP address of the ipad to ssh into the linux box.